# Calculate geometry in IF/ELSE statement using ArcGIS.Pro field calculator

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, if-else

I'm using If/else statement to calculate geometry (field `"LENGTH"`) for features meeting special criteria (the value in `"TYPE"` field does not equal AB201, AB202, AB203, AB204, AB205, AB206). The code is:
Expression box:

```
mycalc(!TYPE!,!LENGTH!)
```

Code Block

```
def mycalc(TYPE,LENGTH):
    if TYPE != 'AB201' or TYPE != 'AB202' or TYPE != 'AB203' or TYPE != 'AB204' or TYPE != 'AB205' or TYPE != 'AB206': 
        return (!shape.length!/1000)
    else:
        return LENGTH
```

So, I get the error

[image]

The command `!shape.length!` calculates geometry in units of the features' coordinate system, which is 'meter' in my case, so I divide it by 1000 (I need kilometers).

I know I can solve this problem by filtering featureclasses or by calculating selected features. But I use this expression in ModelBuilder, which iterates through a file geodatabase.

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing in the geometry into the function which is causing the invalid syntax error. So taking on the excellent advice from @BERA it should be:

```
myCalc(!Type!,!LENGTH!,!Shape!)
```

```py
def myCalc(myTYPE, LENGTH, geom):
    if myTYPE not in ('AB201', 'AB202', 'AB203', 'AB204', 'AB205','AB206'): 
        return (geom.length / 1000)
    else:
        return LENGTH
```

Comment: many thanks! It works!